# Mozilla Firefox is eating up my machine memory even when there's only one tab

Tags: windows-7, browser, firefox, memory-management

Check out this [video link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_z5TdtBP7vw); it proves that Mozilla Firefox continuously increases the size of memory consumed every moment..

What's the matter?

Comment: Does the same happen when you are not using flash?

Comment: yes.. i can provide more video proofs

Comment: though my netbook is having only intel core 2 solo cpu @ 1.40GHz
but check this out.. http://youtu.be/QjNO-yz-hQ8

Comment: Do other browsers do the same thing?

Comment: -1 No, I don't want to check out a video. State your actual problem, which version of firefox you use and what addons you have installed.

Comment: Older versions of Firefox have many memory leaks that would allow something like this to happen, but I think many of them have been fixed last year. Could you give us the version of your Firefox and the list of add-ons (you can copy from the special URL about:support), and if possible the URL of the web page that you were on.

Comment: Newer versions of Firefox have this problem as well. I can verify this.

Comment: Firefox Version: 14.0

        Adblock Plus
        2.1.1

        Disconnect
        0.0.0
        true
        2.0@disconnect.me

        Firebug
        1.10.0
        true
        firebug@software.joehewitt.com

        Speed Dial
        0.9.6.4
        true
        {64161300-e22b-11db-8314-0800200c9a66}

        Test Pilot
        1.2.1
        truetestpilot@labs.mozilla.com

Xpnd.it! short URL expander
1.1a
true
xpndit@long-shore.com

Answer (score 1):

check your add ons and plugins disable them and see if it makes a difference. I installed a gmail plugin which took over 1 gb ram when active. CRazy :-(

Alternately, clear the download history (you may need to exit Firefox and delete the file downloads.rdf file from the profile folder in some cases [4]) and change your Download History settings to remove files from the Download Manager "Upon successful download" to circumvent the problem

more advance options would be to change  the about:config preferences below while these may have an effect on memory consumption but may also affect performance or reduce functionality

Preference   Max memory freed
browser.cache.memory.capacity and browser.cache.memory.enable    14MB
browser.sessionhistory.max_total_viewers

All the best